# Como alterar tipo de projeto no GitHub pelo Visual Studio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, github

Bem, criei um `Reposótirio` no [GitHub](https://github.com/Renancp01/ControlePatrimonial) através do `VisualStudio`

Porém, só que ao dar um `Commit/Push` ele ficou o tipo de projeto sendo `JavaScript`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, quero alterar ele para ser do tipo `C#`. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

O GitHub faz a escolha(Automatica) pela maior % de código com uma determinada linguagem no projeto, no caso tem mais código JS do que c# no seu projeto.

Comment: Então não é possível eu alterar isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é automático, baseado na maior % de código por linguagem.

Assim que você fizer mais `push`s de código C# ele mudará sozinho :)